# Regular expression for finding swear words unless they are football teams

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

In AS3, I have created a nice swear filter routine that imports a list of regular expressions for swear words and combines them into a single regular expression. However, one bit I'm having problem over are football teams, namely ARSENAL and SCUNTHORPE.

Is there a way in a regular expression to block the swearwords *unless* they complete the words to be the above? I tried the following with ARSENAL but it didn't work properly:

```
/arse[^(nal)]/gi
```

The problem is that I cannot parenthesise the letters "nal" because it sees the parentheses as characters rather than a block. It appears to expect at least one extra character after "arse" in order to work. Can I make it so that it will allow one but not the other? How can I group letters together and say "not"?

EDIT: I found elsewhere on Stack some talk of "negative lookahead"s but didn't quite get how I could do that for these two use cases... Any ideas?

Comment: So you'll block almost any foreign text or any cultured person who use foreign words. Because there are MANY words that content fragments similar to rude words. And if somebody cleverer than an oak wants to say something rude, he could do it easily without rude words

Comment: I agree, however, this website is for a UK-only promotion. And it also appeases the client. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Actionscript specifically but in most Regex engines you can use

negative lookahead: `?!`

negative lookbehind: `?<!`

So for Arsenal:

```
/arse(?!nal)/gi
```

And Scunthorp or sHAPPYhorp:

```
/HAPPY(?<!sHAPPY)(?!horp)/gi
```

And Scunthorp will be similar to sHAPPYhorp, left as an assignment for the reader.

Comment: Brilliant thanks! Works great, with one exception... I removed the lookBEHIND bit, otherwise the word sHAPPY wouldn't be caught by the swear filter, which I want it to. I only want the word c**t to be allowed if it is within the word Scunthorpe. Otherwise all good :)

Comment: ActionScript 3.0 tales <?! , too (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e9a.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the word anchor `\b`: `\bswearwordhere\b`.

Of course, you'd have to do with whatever s---ty workaround those ba**ar*s will invent to circumvent your f-*"-ng rules, heh.

Comment: And if they use plurals?  Or double barroled swears?

Comment: Yeah well, that is the difficulty of natural language processing, isn't it? ;)

Comment: sorry, I don't understand how that helps me do a NOT to the search?

Comment: Well, simple: invert your test. If it _matches_ a swear word, you have a problem.

Comment: but that won't work if someone tries to hide a swearword inside another one, unfortunately.